# $\int_{A_n} f(x) d\mu$ converge to $\int_{A } f(x) d\mu$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f$ is integrable on sets $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \ldots \supset A_n \supset \ldots$ and let $A = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$.

Does $\int_{A_n} f(x) d\mu$ converge to $\int_{A } f(x) d\mu$?

I think this is false but I can't prove it, If you can give me some hints please, I'm really stuck in this problem.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I think you can use some version of the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Yea Im trying with that but the theorem os applied for a sequence of measurable function f_n how connect to the sets?

Comment: @Knight write $\int_{A_n}fd\mu = \int \chi_{A_n}fd\mu$ and try to use some theorem. The hypothesis now is $\chi_{A_n}\downarrow \chi_{A}$, that is, $\chi_{A_n}f\downarrow \chi_{A}f$,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first do the following manipulation:
$$
\int_{A_1}fd\mu - \int_{A_n}fd\mu = \int_{A_1\setminus A_n}fd\mu.
$$
Now, note that from the given condition,
$$
0 \leq f\mathcal{X}_{A_1 \setminus A_n}\nearrow f\mathcal{X}_{A_1 \setminus A}.
$$
Hence, from MCT we get,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A_1\setminus A_n}fd\mu = \int_{A_1\setminus A}f d\mu \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_{A_1}fd\mu - \int_{A_n}fd\mu\right)=\int_{A_1}fd\mu - \int_{A} fd\mu \\
 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A_n}fd\mu = \int_A fd\mu
$$
using the fact that $f\mathcal{X}_{A_1}\in L^1(\mu)$. Note that in the absence of this, we would not be able to apply MCT.

**Remark**

This proof somehow mimics the proof regarding continuity of measure, when the sets are diminishing. In that case, if one recalls, there was an additional requirement that measure of one set is finite, which allows us to take set differences and apply monotonicity argument that is valid other way.

Comment: what does it mean $\nearrow $

Comment: Take a sequence of functions $f_n(x)$, we say $f_n \nearrow f$ if $f_n(x)$ is monotonically going to $f(x)$ for every $x$, as $n\to\infty$. It is equivalent to saying $f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) \leq \dots \leq f_n(x) \dots \leq f(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Set $f_n := f \cdot 1_{A_n}$, (so you get $f(x)$ if $x \in A_n$ and zero otherwise). Then, since the $A_n$ are decreasing, $f_n \downarrow f_0 := f \cdot 1_A$ pointwise (a point being in $A$ only if it is in each $A_n$). Now you can apply Monotone Convergence (or Dominated Convergence using $f_1$) to get $\lim_n \int f_n = \int f_0$.

Comment: But MCT works the other way, if you have family of functions $0 \leq f_n \nearrow f$. In the other case, you need extra conditions. See my solution below.

Comment: Since they're bounded between two summable functions, Dominated Convergence implies they're equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working this problem on another [site](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/convergence-of-a-sequence-of-sets.983367/page-2#post-6299380), and look at the link to see my take on the solution. I think I've got most of it understood, thanks for this thread. In case the link doesn't work for whatever reason I have transferred the code to this site's format, and will post the relevant portion of the link here:

Theorem 2) Let $A_n , A\in\mathbb{R}^N$ such that

$$A\subset\cdots\subset A_{n+1}\subset A_n\subset\cdots\subset A_2\subset A_1$$

and let $A:=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ Then for Lebesgue measurable $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{C}$ define the set function $\phi : A_1\to\mathbb{C}$ by

$$\phi (E):=\int_{E} f\, d\mu \, \, \forall E\subset A_1$$

Then,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi (A_n) = \phi (A)$$

which is to say explicitly that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A_n} f\, d\mu = \int_{A} f\, d\mu$$

Proof: Let $f_n:=f\cdot\chi_{A_n}$ and let $f:=f\cdot\chi_{A}$. Then

$$f_1 (x)\geq f_2 (x)\geq\cdots\geq f_n (x)\geq f_{n+1} (x)\geq\cdots f(x)$$

hence by the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem with $f_1 (x) \geq | f_n (x) | \, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^N,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi (A_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A_n} f\, d\mu = \int_{A} f\, d\mu =\phi (A) $$

and the theorem is demonstrated.
*End of transferred code from linked site.*

We are however caught up as to whether any further properties of f must be assumed for the following equality to hold:

$ \int_A \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} f\circ \chi(A_n) \right)\,d\mu =  \int_A  f \circ \chi\left(\displaystyle{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}}A_n\right)  \,d\mu$

e.g. is boundedness required or Lebesgue integrable and $A_n$ measurable enough?

Note to moderator: I see the tip in the box below the editor that I should avoid asking for help, but I don not see the point of creating my own identical post (identical to the OP) just to ask a simple question. I linked my answer and reformatted the code to post here, it's slightly different than the other answers to this problem--I hope this is well with you for my first post on this site.